# echo checkmark in shellscript (zsh) how-to

Tags: shell-script, zsh, unicode, escape-characters, rxvt

Why is this checkmark not printed correctly when executing my shellscript, even though echo alone outputs corrctly?

script:

```
#!/bin/sh
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
NC='\033[0m' # no color
echo "enter your provider's auth code"
stty -echo
read authcode
oathtool --totp -b $authcode | xclip -i
echo "${YELLOW}\u2714 code copied to clipboard${NC}"
```

terminal output: *\u2714 code copied to clipboard*

standalone command:

```
echo "\u2714 checkmark"
```

terminal output:
*✔ checkmark*

My shell is *zsh 5.8 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu)*
using the *rxvt-unicode-256color* terminal

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas ! Exactly as you say. Changing the shebang to `#! /bin/zsh` does the trick. Much obliged!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shebang has `/bin/sh`, and I doubt `/bin/sh` is `zsh` on your system. `zsh` is not one of Debian's approved `sh` implementations. And anyway I would advise against using non-standard-`sh` syntax in `sh` script.

`\u2714` is not standard `echo` syntax. It will (likely) be standard inside `$'...'` in the next major revision of the POSIX standard, but not in arguments to `echo` or `printf`, and anyway Debian's default `sh` implementation (`dash`) doesn't support `$'...'` yet.

`\uXXXX` is recognised by `zsh`'s `printf` (in the format argument or arguments for `%b`), `print` (except with `-r`aw) and `echo` (except with `-E` or if the `bsdecho` option is enabled) builtins and inside its `$'...'` (that's the first shell where those `\uXXXX` sequences were introduced inside `$'...'`, the `$'...'` quotes themselves being from ksh93).

Change the shebang to `#! /bin/zsh -` if you want to use `zsh` features in your script.

Then, you can use more zsh features such as:

```
print -P '%B%F{yellow}\u2714 whatever%f%b'
```

Where `%F{yellow}` with `P`rompt expansion is expanded to the correct code for your terminal to change the `F`oreground colour to *yellow* (and `%f` to reset the foreground colour to the default, and `%B` / `%b` to enable / disable *bold* like with your `\033[1m`).

In `zsh`, you can also do:

```
IFS= read -rs 'authcode?enter auth code: '
```

To issue a prompt and enable `s`ilent input more reliably.

In any case, like in `sh`, you'll likely want `-r` and `IFS=` to avoid `read` mangling the input.

You could also use `set -o pipefail` for that `oathtool | xclip` pipeline to be considered as having failed if either `oathtool` or `xclip` failed (not just `xclip`).

Note that if the locale's character encoding doesn't have the U+2714 character, `print` will fail with a `zsh: character not in range` error.

---

In standard `sh` + utilities syntax, the syntax should rather be:

```
#! /bin/sh -
bold_yellow='\033[1;33m'
nc='\033[m' # no color
if [ "$(locale charmap)" = UTF-8 ]; then
  check_mark='\0342\0234\0224'
else
  check_mark='[X]'
fi

saved_tty_settings=$(stty -g)
trap 'stty "$saved_tty_settings"' EXIT ALRM TERM INT QUIT
stty -echo
printf >&2 "enter your provider's auth code: "
IFS= read -r authcode &&
  secret=$(oathtool --totp -b "$authcode") &&
  printf %s "$secret" | xclip -i &&
  printf '%b\n' "${bold_yellow}${check_mark} code copied to clipboard${nc}"
```

Here hardcoding the colouring escape sequences, and hardcoding the UTF-8 encoding of U+2714 only if the locale's charmap is UTF-8.

Or you could do:

```
check_mark=$(printf '\342\234\224' | iconv -f UTF-8 2> /dev/null) ||
  check_mark='[X]'
```

To get the `check_mark` in the locale's charmap if it has one (and `UTF-8` is supported on the system) and `[X]` otherwise. GB18030 is the only other charmap that I know that has U+2714. It's also an encoding of Unicode, used mostly in China (like in the `zh_CN.gb18030` locale on Debian).

Comment: Wow. I learnt a lot in a few minutes, thanks!!

My working script now looks like this:

```
#! /bin/zsh
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
NC='\033[0m' # no color
IFS= read -rs 'authcode?enter auth code: '
oathtool --totp -b $authcode | xclip -i
print -P '%F{yellow}\u2714 code copied to clipboard%f'
```

Comment: Actually I now go with the generic version you kindly posted, so it works not only with zsh.
I am obviously new to shell-scripting. To make this even better, can you help me handle errors nicer for oauthtool? Entering the wrong auth code now outputs "oauthtool: not found"...

Comment: @user7339343, the `pipefail` option would help you there. It will also be in the next POSIX version, but is not supported by `dash` yet. BTW,  I changed `oathtool` to `oauthool` thinking it was a typo on your part, but maybe it wasn't ?

Comment: It is actually `oathtool`, see https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/oath-toolkit
I will look into `pipefail`, thanks!

Comment: @kevinmoilar, thanks. I've reverted it. I also broke down the pipeline into a var assignment and then feed to xclip so `oathtool`'s exit code can be checked without the need to `pipefail`.